# updating a local repo when its remote proxy repo is re-indexing in Nexus

Tags: nexus

I have a nexus repo locally that is a proxy to a remote repo. The update interval is set to one hour. 
1) When the remote repo is re-indexing, and the update kicks off after one hour interval, will the index in the local repo be out of whack ( we see that many times our local repo is in a bad state and we need to re-index and we are wondering if this might be the reason)
2) Am thinking I will turn off the update interval and update manually when required.

Thoughts/Suggestions/Tips??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The update indexes task is not designed to be run that often, and it is not necessary to do this. There is a performance penalty paid when running these this often. Schedule a single "update indexes" task to run daily against "all repositories", that is all that is needed for search index maintenance. It does everything needed for all repositories (downloads remote indexes, publishes indexes, and fixes up discrepancies between search indexes and repository storage).

Search indexes are only used to support interactive search for artifacts in the Nexus UI, they are not used for artifact resolution in builds.  New artifacts will be available for your builds immediately after they are published on the remote server even if you never update search indexes.

That said, UI artifact search will function properly while the update indexes task is running.

> we see that many times our local repo is in a bad state and we need to re-index and we are wondering if this might be the reason

Something else is going wrong with your server if you need to run re-index so frequently.  Have you checked the logs to see if exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check the logs to see if I have any clues